# How to add custom field in table using Joomla?

Tags: database, joomla, custom-fields

I am new in Joomla. I want to add custom fields in registration and I also want to save its data to `jos_users`.

How do I add a custom field in `jos_users` table?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla core doesnt allow adding custom fields to registration form. However with the help of some add-ons  custom fields could be created, check these:

- [Juser](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/2034)
- [Extended reg](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/14303)

Now I don't know if those extensions save the data in to `jos_user`. Probably they crate a new table because of the custom fields. But they probably keep that table in sync with `jos_user`. You should ask this to the developer of the extension or try it yourself and see.

Another option is to modify joomla core yourself. If you add fields to the jos_users table in Joomla 1.5, you need to modify the following files:

libraries/joomla/database/table/user.php
libraries/joomla/user/user.php
com_user/views/user/tmpl/form.php
com_user/views/register/tmpl/default.php
com_users/views/user/tmpl/form.php

Answer (score 1):

I read that modifying the core files is wrong because when you update to the latest version of joomla all the changes will be gone. I guess that if you think you will never update to the latest version then try modifying the core files. One awesome link is

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dk_86nHu3AM

Answer (score 1):

You can now add fields to the user signup form, natively, straight out of the box, without additional plugins or modules. 
[image: Select the Fields and/or field group and customize to suit.]